# How can I turn on dark mode on here?

Tags: feature-request

Can anyone tell me how I can turn on dark mode on this website?

This bright white is already burning a hole in my retinas.

Why is there not just a button at the bottom or top of the webpage at all times? That would be the easiest way to do it.

Comment: This belongs on Meta [flagged to migrate]. Dark mode is a site by site support, not yet global across SE. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111399/dark-mode-for-stack-exchange-sites [& search main Meta for a hundred others]

Comment: Super User doesn't have one.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't see any problem in here. Just make a toggle, if you want dark mode, enable it. If you don't want it, disable it. Simple as that.

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer - The toggle does not exist. I also don’t understand the problem, difficult to enable something, that doesn’t exist

Answer (score 4):

Right now, Stack Overflow is the only Stack Exchange site that has an official Dark Mode built in to the user settings, so I guess you're out of luck.

Comment: You can use browser extensions like Stylish or Dark Reader, for now.

Comment: Not for lack of asking. 

Comment: In the mean time, for chrome users, maybe this will help: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-mode/dmghijelimhndkbmpgbldicpogfkceaj

Answer (score 4):

Desktop:

- Chrome + dark mode flag on (`chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark`)
- Firefox + Dark Reader extension

Android phones:

- Opera's built-in dark mode
- Firefox + Dark Reader extension.